Sum with constraints in maple or mathematica
I'm looking for a code in Maple or Mathematica to evaluate and give a list of terms in expressions like
$\newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}$
$$
\sum_{a\ +\ b\ +\ c\ =\ 6}\on{f}\left(a\right)\on{f}\left(b\right)\on{f}\left(c\right)
$$
There is no special thing about $6$ just a random number and can be replaced by any $k$.

$\tt Mathematica$: $$\verb* Sum[If[a + b + c == 6,f[a] + f[b] + f[c]  ,0],{c,-Infinity,Infinity},{b,-Infinity,Infinity},{a,-Infinity,Infinity}]*$$

wkmath: are $a,b,c$ supposed to be integers?  positive integers?  nonnegative integers?  what?
